# Regression Table in Beamer Presentation and can a link be attached to open the table on a separate page?

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to show my regression table on my beamer presentation. However, I am facing difficulties adjusting the table size in both the normal document and the presentation. Plus, is there a way to attach something on a line that opens another embedded LaTeX page containing the table?

The code of the table is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{center}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
VARIABLES & IV First Stage & Jute Acres per Cap & Jute Output Per Cap & Jute Yield & Rice Acres Per Cap \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Log Distance from Border & -0.555*** &  &  &  &  \\
 & (0.0680) &  &  &  &  \\
Jute Acres/100, 1931 & -0.00217*** & 0.0126*** & 1.152*** & 0.0432 & 0.0590*** \\
 & (0.000551) & (0.00113) & (0.0945) & (0.0353) & (0.0205) \\
Pop. Density/100, 1956 & -0.0762*** & 0.0423 & 4.346 & 10.50*** & 1.458** \\
 & (0.0181) & (0.0395) & (3.307) & (1.237) & (0.719) \\
Big City Dummy & 0.327 & -0.462 & -44.05 & -18.21 & -13.28 \\
 & (0.235) & (0.471) & (39.43) & (14.75) & (8.576) \\
Male Literacy, 1956 & 0.0311*** & -0.0215 & -1.757 & -1.916*** & -0.794*** \\
 & (0.00658) & (0.0151) & (1.262) & (0.472) & (0.274) \\
Minority Share, 1931 & 0.0573*** & -0.0230 & -2.353 & -0.247 & -1.693*** \\
 & (0.00584) & (0.0229) & (1.915) & (0.716) & (0.416) \\
Nadia Dummy & 2.060*** & -0.981 & -51.70 & -3.872 & -19.71 \\
 & (0.728) & (1.568) & (131.3) & (49.14) & (28.57) \\
Sqrt. of Migrant Share &  & 0.723*** & 61.53*** & 2.799 & 15.61*** \\
 &  & (0.244) & (20.45) & (7.652) & (4.448) \\
Constant & 2.820*** & 0.112 & 10.59 & 34.17*** & 37.28*** \\
 & (0.433) & (0.340) & (28.45) & (10.64) & (6.187) \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 \\
R-squared &  & 0.460 & 0.502 & 0.380 & -0.113 \\
 KP F Statistic &  & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ Standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
\end{center}
```

The code I'm trying on beamer

```
\begin{frame}{Final Table}
\begin{small}
\centering
        \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
            max width=.9\textwidth}{
\include{table}
}
\end{small}   
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is he same table that fit in both the article and the presentation without any link.

If this data are not the final results and you want/need update often both document with a single edit, you can remove from `\begin{tabulary}` to `\end{tablary}` in both documents and paste it in an completely empty file (said `table.tex`) and then just add `\input{table}`
[image: mwe1]
[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Final Table}
\tiny
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCCCCC} \toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
VARIABLES & IV First Stage & Jute Acres per Cap & Jute Output Per Cap & Jute Yield & Rice Acres Per Cap \\\midrule
Log Distance from Border & -0.555*** &  &  &  &  \\
 & (0.0680) &  &  &  &  \\
Jute Acres/100, 1931 & -0.00217*** & 0.0126*** & 1.152*** & 0.0432 & 0.0590*** \\
 & (0.000551) & (0.00113) & (0.0945) & (0.0353) & (0.0205) \\
Pop. Density/100, 1956 & -0.0762*** & 0.0423 & 4.346 & 10.50*** & 1.458** \\
 & (0.0181) & (0.0395) & (3.307) & (1.237) & (0.719) \\
Big City Dummy & 0.327 & -0.462 & -44.05 & -18.21 & -13.28 \\
 & (0.235) & (0.471) & (39.43) & (14.75) & (8.576) \\
Male Literacy, 1956 & 0.0311*** & -0.0215 & -1.757 & -1.916*** & -0.794*** \\
 & (0.00658) & (0.0151) & (1.262) & (0.472) & (0.274) \\
Minority Share, 1931 & 0.0573*** & -0.0230 & -2.353 & -0.247 & -1.693*** \\
 & (0.00584) & (0.0229) & (1.915) & (0.716) & (0.416) \\
Nadia Dummy & 2.060*** & -0.981 & -51.70 & -3.872 & -19.71 \\
 & (0.728) & (1.568) & (131.3) & (49.14) & (28.57) \\
Sqrt. of Migrant Share &  & 0.723*** & 61.53*** & 2.799 & 15.61*** \\
 &  & (0.244) & (20.45) & (7.652) & (4.448) \\
Constant & 2.820*** & 0.112 & 10.59 & 34.17*** & 37.28*** \\
 & (0.433) & (0.340) & (28.45) & (10.64) & (6.187) \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 \\
R-squared &  & 0.460 & 0.502 & 0.380 & -0.113 \\
 KP F Statistic &  & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 \\ \bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{ Standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabulary}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCCCCC} \toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
VARIABLES & IV First Stage & Jute Acres per Cap & Jute Output Per Cap & Jute Yield & Rice Acres Per Cap \\\midrule
Log Distance from Border & -0.555*** &  &  &  &  \\
 & (0.0680) &  &  &  &  \\
Jute Acres/100, 1931 & -0.00217*** & 0.0126*** & 1.152*** & 0.0432 & 0.0590*** \\
 & (0.000551) & (0.00113) & (0.0945) & (0.0353) & (0.0205) \\
Pop. Density/100, 1956 & -0.0762*** & 0.0423 & 4.346 & 10.50*** & 1.458** \\
 & (0.0181) & (0.0395) & (3.307) & (1.237) & (0.719) \\
Big City Dummy & 0.327 & -0.462 & -44.05 & -18.21 & -13.28 \\
 & (0.235) & (0.471) & (39.43) & (14.75) & (8.576) \\
Male Literacy, 1956 & 0.0311*** & -0.0215 & -1.757 & -1.916*** & -0.794*** \\
 & (0.00658) & (0.0151) & (1.262) & (0.472) & (0.274) \\
Minority Share, 1931 & 0.0573*** & -0.0230 & -2.353 & -0.247 & -1.693*** \\
 & (0.00584) & (0.0229) & (1.915) & (0.716) & (0.416) \\
Nadia Dummy & 2.060*** & -0.981 & -51.70 & -3.872 & -19.71 \\
 & (0.728) & (1.568) & (131.3) & (49.14) & (28.57) \\
Sqrt. of Migrant Share &  & 0.723*** & 61.53*** & 2.799 & 15.61*** \\
 &  & (0.244) & (20.45) & (7.652) & (4.448) \\
Constant & 2.820*** & 0.112 & 10.59 & 34.17*** & 37.28*** \\
 & (0.433) & (0.340) & (28.45) & (10.64) & (6.187) \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 & 182 \\
R-squared &  & 0.460 & 0.502 & 0.380 & -0.113 \\
 KP F Statistic &  & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 & 66.43 \\ \bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{ Standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran into some issues with respect to beamer. I keep getting the error: Overfull \hbox error. If I try to include \input{table}, the overleaf document disappears. I tried to include:\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio}. It improves the formatting in table.tex but the code in the beamer presentation does not seem to work.

Comment: The `Overfull \hbox` are warnings, not errors. It is nothing terrible when they are small (0.5-2 pt) and you cannot note the issue inspecting visually the PDF.  About  the `\input` issue, with  
`\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Final Table}
\tiny
\input{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}` I obtain exactly the same ouptut, so you are doing something wrong, as put `table.tex` in the wrong place or maybe `table.tex` is not exactly the removed `tabulary` environment, but from here I can only guess ...

Comment: Found the error: I was using this speficiation: ```\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}```